# How to sort a Python dict's keys by value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this

`{ "keyword1":3 , "keyword2":1 , "keyword3":5 , "keyword4":2 }`

And I would like to convert it DESC and create a list of just the keywords. Eg, this would return

`["keyword3" , "keyword1" , "keyword4" , "keyword2"]`

**All examples I found use lambda and I'm not very strong with that. Is there a way I could loop through this, and sort them as I go**? Thanks for any suggestions.

PS: I could create the initial dict differently if it would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @Teepeemm I think this version of the question is better, actually.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use

```
res = list(sorted(theDict, key=theDict.__getitem__, reverse=True))
```

(You don't need the `list` in Python 2.x)

The `theDict.__getitem__` is actually equivalent to `lambda x: theDict[x]`.

(A lambda is just an anonymous function. For example

```
>>> g = lambda x: x + 5
>>> g(123)
128
```

This is equivalent to

```
>>> def h(x):
...   return x + 5
>>> h(123)
128
```

)

Comment: +1 Used this to numerically sort filenames containing integers. names = {}
for f in sys.argv[1:] : 
    robj = re.search( "([0-9]+)", f )
    if robj is not None :
        names[f] = int(robj.group(1))
    
res = list(sorted(names,key=names.__getitem__))
print "\n".join(res)

Comment: The `list` call isn't needed in 3.x, either.

Answer (score 19):

```
>>> d={ "keyword1":3 , "keyword2":1 , "keyword3":5 , "keyword4":2 }
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
['keyword3', 'keyword1', 'keyword4', 'keyword2']
```

Answer (score 2):

i always did it this way....are there advantages to using the sorted method?

```
keys = dict.keys()
keys.sort( lambda x,y: cmp(dict[x], dict[y]) )
```

whoops didnt read the part about not using lambda =(

Answer (score 2):

I would come up with something like this:

```
[k for v, k in sorted(((v, k) for k, v in theDict.items()), reverse=True)]
```

But [KennyTM's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417760/how-to-sort-a-python-dict-by-value/3417773#3417773) is much nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to sort a dict, only to get a representation of a dict that is sorted. Dicts are inherently order less, but other types, such as lists and tuples, are not. So you need a sorted representation, which will be a list—probably a list of tuples. For instance,

```
'''
Sort the dictionary by score. if the score is same then sort them by name 
{ 
 'Rahul'  : {score : 75} 
 'Suhas' : {score : 95} 
 'Vanita' : {score : 56} 
 'Dinesh' : {score : 78} 
 'Anil'  : {score : 69} 
 'Anup'  : {score : 95} 
} 
'''
import operator

x={'Rahul' : {'score' : 75},'Suhas' : {'score' : 95},'Vanita' : {'score' : 56}, 
   'Dinesh' : {'score' : 78},'Anil' : {'score' : 69},'Anup' : {'score' : 95} 
  }
sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_x
```

**output:**

```
[('Vanita', {'score': 56}), ('Anil', {'score': 69}), ('Rahul', {'score': 75}), ('Dinesh', {'score': 78}), ('Anup', {'score': 95}), ('Suhas', {'score': 95})]
```