# sort values and return list of keys from dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like `A = {'Name1':34, 'Name2': 12, 'Name6': 46,....}`.

How can I get a list of keys sorted by the values, i.e. `[Name2, Name1, Name6....]`?

Comment: thanks for the advice @Felix, but I searched before I asked and the answers are not what I need.

Comment: I have to disagree, there are a lot of similar questions with the answer you are searching for. E.g. the second highest voted answer in the question  I linked to provides the same solution as the highest voted answer here or e.g. [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417760/how-to-sort-a-python-dict-by-value). You might have to try some things out, but the question definitely was here already.

Comment: "the answers are not what I need".  A useless statement.  What is missing from the existing answers?  **How** are they incomplete or misleading?  **What** makes your question somehow unique? Please be **specific**.

Comment: The canonical [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183) considers a problem where the output is expected to have both keys and values (and where answers explain that dictionaries are inherently not ordered, and thus not sortable, in order Python versions). However, this question asks only to get the keys; there are other approaches to the problem besides "sort the items (the big canonical) and then extract the keys from that sorted result". As such, I instead re-closed this as a duplicate of a lesser-known, but good quality and more specific question.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) with the [`get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method as a key (dictionary keys can be accessed by [iterating](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict)):

```
sorted(A, key=A.get)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `sorted`'s `key` argument

```
sorted(d, key=d.get)
```

Answer (score 6):

`sorted(a.keys(), key=a.get)`

This sorts the keys, and for each key, uses `a.get` to find the value to use as its sort value.

Comment: Note that it is unnecessary to use `a.keys`, which makes a list of the keys. `a` (or `a.iterkeys()`) is already an iterable over the keys of the dict a.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's unnecessary, but I think it reads better.  I think of dicts as containers of pairs, not containers of keys.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use:

```
items = dict.items()
items.sort(key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))
sorted_keys = [ item[0] for item in items ]
```

The `key` argument to sort is a callable that returns the sort key to use. In this case, I'm returning a tuple of `(value, key)`, but you could just return the value (ie, `key=lambda item: item[1]`) if you'd like.

Comment: The other solution is simpler and easier to read for me.

Comment: In case you're running into linter issues, use `sorted`:

items = sorted(dict.items(),  key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))