# Python: function to sort a dictionary by value and return only a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to write a function that takes a dictionary and returns the list of ONLY keys sorted descending by the value.
So let's say I have:
cars_1 = {"Opel": 1977, "Ford": 1965, "BWM": 1981, "Jaguar": 1971}
and the result would be:
[BMW, Opel, Jaguar, Ford]
So the cars are sorted not by the name of the car but by the value.

And I don't want to import any built-in Python fuctions

So far I have this:

```
def cars_desc():
    cars_1 = {"Opel": 1977, "Ford": 1965, "BWM": 1981, "Jaguar": 1971}
    cars_2= sorted(cars_1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in cars_2:
    print(i[0])
```

this returns good results but not list. Does anyone know how to return a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340019/sort-values-and-return-list-of-keys-from-dict-python

Comment: You can just wrap the result ```cars_2 = list(cars_2)```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension instead

```
cars = [i[0] for i in cars_2]
print(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this

```
sorted(list(cars_1.items()), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

The return value of .items() method is a view object so you need to convert it to list. Hope it helps.